# how to append different set of values in list

Tags: python, list

I need to append different value in the list.

I have some ranges like:

```
1-20, I need value is 0
21-30, I need random values between 1 to 50
31-56, I need random values between 200 to 1000
57-77, I need random values between 1 to 50 
78-98 I need value is 0
```

I need the list which contains 98 index and the values is according to above ranges.

Comment: Use append or extend

Comment: please, add the example of your attempt

Comment: yes I am working on that part

Comment: Is the question over how to create random numbers? Or how to create a composite list with different ranges? Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward way is to use numpy to generate random integers and append in a loop.

```
from numpy import random
l = []
for i in range(98):
    if i < 20 or i >= 78:
        l.append(0)
    elif 20 <= i <= 30
        l.append(random.randint(1, 50)
    elif ...
        and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

This function takes a number and generates the desired one based on your request.

```
import random
def gen_number(num):
    if 21<=num<=30:
        return random.randint(1, 51)
    elif 31<=num<=56:
        return random.randint(200, 1001)
    elif 57<=num<=77:
        return random.randint(1, 51)
    else:
        return 0
```

And here you use the function and get the result.

```
result = []
for i in range(1, 99):
    result.append(gen_number(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python lists can be updated or initialised in many ways. You could create a zero-initialised list and then set the various ranges to the values you want. That would be cleaner.

Something like:

```
total_size = 98
my_list = [0 for i in range(total_size)]
# Use list slicing to set the ranges
range_start, range_stop = 0, 5
my_list[range_start:range_stop] = [1 for i in range(range_stop - range_start)]  # 1s for the first 5 elements
# Whatever you want for the other slices.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but could you please update your answer I am getting some error

Comment: @abhispdy, I've fixed it, but for future reference you are more likely to get what you want if you can explain what the error is.